# CentOS - No route to host when trying git clone

Tags: centos7, firewalld

I'm trying to clone a repo from github by using the command:
git clone https://github.com/

However, I'm getting the below error:

fatal: unable to access "https://github.com/...." : Failed connect to ip addr : port; No route to host

I have tried several things including turning the firewall off.
**systemctl status firewalld**
shows inactive status.

Does anyone have an idea what I might be missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the system has access to internet. It can be a problem with the nameserver. It should be defined here: `/etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: I checked /etc/resolve.conf. It has the following contents:

# Generated by NetworkManager \n
nameserver <some ip address> \n
What can I change here?

Comment: do you have active internet connection on the system?